# Slow delete in VB

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm using the following code to delete a table in VB (Visual Studio 2017 using Access database):

```
For v = 1 To Me.MasterDataBindingSource.Count
    Me.MasterDataBindingSource.Current.delete()
    Me.MasterDataBindingSource.MoveNext()
Next
Me.Validate()
Me.MasterDataBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataWarehouseDataSet)
```

This works but is very slow for my 250k+ records.  Am I taking the correct approach?
Thanks J

Comment: Would you not be better off writing an sql statement, and executing it, to delete the rows of your requirement?

Comment: Hi Andrew, many thanks... could you point me in a direction to read how to do that? Cheers J

Comment: You could also delete the rows in the datatable which would be fast, then update via the dataadapter,